# In kotlin, When I overload the inc() operator, I get an error

Tags: kotlin, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

The following code shows an overload of the unaryMinus function on the Point object, which works fine.

```
data class Point(val x: Int, val y: Int)
operator fun Point.unaryMinus(): Point = Point(-x, -y)
```

Similar to the above, overloading the inc () function will cause an error.

```
operator fun Point.inc(): Point {
        return Point(this.x + 1, this.y + 1)
    }
```

The error contents are as follows.

> Error:(29, 4) Gradle: 'operator' modifier is inapplicable on this
>   function: receiver must be a supertype of the return type

What's wrong?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/X3LJa0)

Comment: thanks chris, but it happens in the following environment.
Android Studio 3.0.1
kotlin 1.1.60-release-Studio3.0-1

Comment: I tried it with Kotlin 1.1.60 (in IntelliJ) and also cannot reproduce this. Looking at the error message: are you sure that you don't have something else named `Point` in scope that is not the same as your data class `Point`?

Comment: Are you defining the `inc` function inside the `Point` class? If you are, don't specify `Point.` in the function declaration.

Comment: @hanburn, [Still can't reproduce](https://imgur.com/a/gDJoe) with the same AS and Kotlin versions.